# Alexa skill not invoked in the Amazon Alexa app, but it works in the development console

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When the skill is under development, I can invoke it in the development console. In the Echo or the Amazon Alexa app the skill is not invoking.

The skill is showing under the skills & games tab in the app and it is enabled.

Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you enabled the "Test is enabled for this skill" switch in your alexa skill web? Also make sure skill is getting listed in "Dev skills" under Your skills section on Alexa app.

Comment: I have same issue, I can see Dev skill enabled in my skills but not able to invoke it in the app, but I can test it on dev portal, any idea what is missing?

Comment: @NaveenKumar it is not working with this, can you please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Are you able to see your skill in "Dev Skills" on your mobile app? Try to search the app in your mobile Alexa app skill section.
Also enabled the "Test is enabled for this skill"  on your Alexa account skill.

Comment: @NaveenKumarI can't find this "test is enabled for this skill" setting, has something changed or am I just looking from a wrong place? Please advise

Answer (score 6):

This could be because of the language you have selected in the Alexa app or Echo device. If you have developed the skill in English (India) and if you app/Echo device is configured with English (US). The skill won't work, just like what you are experiencing.

**Make sure that the Alexa app, your Echo device and the skill you developed are all in same language.**

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem when I was trying to get it done using alexa app on mobile. To solve this problem change your device language(mobile phone language from settings) to the language of the skill which you have developed(in my case it was English(UK)) and then restart the alexa app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well, changing the device/mobile application language to the language in the development console (English (GB)) solved the issue

Comment: Hi 

i did this but the skill on alexa app is not showing the latest invocation name.

Answer (score 0):

@johndoe answer did work for me.

Let me give the step by steps as on this date.

go to **alexa developer console  -> skills tab**
https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask

see what is the language of your skill.
mine is english / United States

Now go to alexa app on your phone
click on **more in the bottom bar** of the app.

click  on **settings** -> **alexa app settings** -> change language to the one in your developer console.

now again click on more in bottom bar **settings** -> **device settings** -> select device -> **click on gear icon in top right side** -> change language to the one in your developer console.

now it should work.

if it doesnt work -change language in your phone settings , restart alexa app , restart alexa device.

now it should most likely work.

Feel free to HMU.

cheers.